# UK nationals live and work in Italy 90 days rule

Tags: united-kingdom, italy

As per the UK government [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-italy#working-in-italy), you (UK nationals) must register as an Italian resident (in Italian) if you want to stay in Italy for more than 3 months. But, it doesn't state how this 90 days can be reset. If I leave Italy to go back to the UK, how soon I can go back to Italy to work again? Disregard the Brexit situation.

Comment: Why not just register? Surely going to the appropriate local authorities to fill out a form cannot be more onerous than doing a visa run (as it were) to the UK.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain *why* you don't want to register.

Comment: Because of earlier questions (although those were from non-EEA citizens), are you working as a nanny or a caregiver?